# Jquery first checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I want create a form. The form has 15 questions. Every questions has 4 answers. Visitors can select minimum 1 and maximum 2 answers for a question. It's okay, i do it.

If visitor select 1 answer, i can read value of the selected answer. If visitor select 2 answers, i can read values too. But i need know which is first selected and which is second selected. Because; if visitor select 3rd answer, then selected 1st answer;

- I need get the value and i need get 2 point for first selected answer
- I need get the value and i need get 1 point for 2nd selected answer

In my example 3rd answer's value is green and 1st answer's value is red. So i need get "green-2" value from the 3rd answer and get "red-1" value from the 1st answer.

How can i do that?

My code is here :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Personal Information</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <p><strong>How are you today?</strong></p>
         <input type="checkbox" class="limited" id="q1a" value="red">Perfect<br>
         <input type="checkbox" class="limited" id="q1b" value="yellow">Good<br>
         <input type="checkbox" class="limited" id="q1c" value="green">Normal<br>
         <input type="checkbox" class="limited" id="q1d" value="blue">Bad<br>
      </form>
   </body>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          var checkboxes = $('.limited');
          checkboxes.on('click', function() {
              var limit = 2;
              var selected = checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
              if (selected > limit) {
                  alert("You can select maximum " + limit + " answer");
                  $(this).prop('checked', false);
              }
          });
      });
   </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkboxes = $('.limited');
  checkboxes.on('click', function() {
    var checkedcheckBox = $('.limited:checked').length;
    // check if any checkbox selected
    if( checkedcheckBox  >= 0 && checkedcheckBox <= 2){

      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        if(checkedcheckBox == 2){
          $('.limited:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        $(this).val($(this).val()+'-'+ checkedcheckBox);
        alert($(this).val());
      }else{
        if(checkedcheckBox < 2){
          $('.limited:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        var SplitIt = $(this).val().split('-');
        var prevVal = SplitIt[0];
        var numBeside = parseInt(SplitIt[1]);
        $('.limited:checked').each(function(){
          var SplitIt_in = $(this).val().split('-');
          var prevVal_in = SplitIt_in[0];
          var numBeside_in = parseInt(SplitIt_in[1]);
          if(numBeside_in > numBeside){
            $(this).val(prevVal_in+'-'+(numBeside_in -1));
          }
        });
        $(this).val(prevVal);
        alert($(this).val());
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/hLgcd8nh/4/)

Comment: Wrong. If you uncheck the first and change your mind to another one, in the meantime the one that had the `1` value and was left checked should turn to `2` since now becomes the "first clicked" (since was left alone).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I already removed some from his own code because that's just the point he/her can starts from

Comment: If OP focuses on what I've said he'll notice that what he's trying to do is a brainf and it's neither user-friendly. If a user checkes two checkboxes, than removes the checkbox from the first checked one, it's not at all logical even to think about that suddenly the second-checked now suddenly has a higher value than just a second before.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan what a long code :( .. Finally I got it to work :) wohooow :) .. and to be honest .. I think its not a good idea for doing it this way .. whatever .. its ok right now

Comment: Mohamed-Yousef, thank you. But it has 2 problems;

- If i select answer-1, it says "red-1" but i want "red-2". Then if i select answer-4, it says "blue-2" but i want "blue-1". I mean first selected = 2 and second selected = 1.

- Then if i uncheck answer-1, it says "red" but i want "blue-2". I mean if i uncheck which has "2", other checked must be automatically 2.

Answer (score 0):

With ownership of HTML5 for Checkbox.

Code:   checked="true"

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Personal Information</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <p><strong>How are you today?</strong></p>
         <input type="checkbox" class="limited" id="q1a" 
                checked="true" value="red">Perfect<br>
         <input type="checkbox" class="limited" id="q1b" value="yellow">Good<br>
         <input type="checkbox" class="limited" id="q1c" value="green">Normal<br>
         <input type="checkbox" class="limited" id="q1d" value="blue">Bad<br>
      </form>
   </body>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          var checkboxes = $('.limited');
          checkboxes.on('click', function() {
              var limit = 2;
              var selected = checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
              if (selected > limit) {
                  alert("You can select maximum " + limit + " answer");
                  $(this).prop('checked', false);
              }
          });
      });
   </script>
</html>
```

In the image changes to the code are:

[image]

hope the information is usefull. goodbye: @locoalien

Comment: Hi @locoalien,

This is not my question. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var checkboxes = $('.limited');
      var checkboxes_click_order = [];
      checkboxes.on('click', function() {
          var limit = 2;
          var selected = checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
          if (selected > limit) {
              alert("You can select maximum " + limit + " answer");
              $(this).prop('checked', false);
          } else {
            if ($(this).prop('checked') && (checkboxes_click_order.indexOf($(this).val()) < 0)) {
              checkboxes_click_order.push($(this).val());
            } else {
              checkboxes_click_order.splice(checkboxes_click_order.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
            }
            console.log(checkboxes_click_order); // This is the order of the selection
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi neilrioszamora. It's very good. But i want see results on the page. Maybe can i show results on the page (maybe on a div)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Personal Information</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <p><strong>How are you today?</strong></p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="limited" id="q1a" value="red">Perfect<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="limited" id="q1b" value="yellow">Good<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="limited" id="q1c" value="green">Normal<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="limited" id="q1d" value="blue">Bad<br>
</form>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var checkboxes = $('.limited');
    checkboxes.on('click', function() {
        var limit = 2;
        var selected = checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
        var count =  limit - selected;
        //updated code
        var first= checkboxes.filter('.first').val();
        var second;
        console.info(count);
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
            switch (count) {
                case -1:
                {
                    alert("You can select maximum " + limit + " answer");
                    $(this).prop('checked', false);
                }
                    break;
                case 1:
                {       
                        //updated code
                        checkboxes.removeClass('first');
                        first = $(this).val()
                        //updated code
                        $(this).addClass('first');
                    alert(first + " = 2")
                }
                    break;
                case 0:
                {
                    second = $(this).val();
                    alert(first + " = 2, " + second + " = 1")
                }
                    break;
            }
        }

        /*if (selected > limit) {
         alert("You can select maximum " + limit + " answer");
         $(this).prop('checked', false);
         }*/
    });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

I put up a variable `'count'` which means that the remaining amount of checkbox items allowed to be clicked.

Then use a switch statement to judge the input order and integrated your code in my `'case -1'` situation.

But when the amount of clickable checkbox becomes larger,it seems that it will become a big trouble.

Comment: When answering questions it is best to explain in more detail rather than just posting code so that it can be more easily understood by other users of the site.

Comment: @Tristan Thanks for your advice :);

Comment: Hi @xxw 

This is perfect. I added some codes to your codes. So i can get real answers. But i have i problem with my codes. Could you please check it and suggest a solution?

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/underspeed/7Lpm0pbt/)

Comment: @OnderYilmaz Sure!Some code has been added in my updated answer which based on your code from [link](http://jsfiddle.net/g0yx7k3r/).
My solution is to add a class 'first' to mark the checkbox which you clicked firstly.
You can easily through $('.first') to find firstly clicked checkbox in the callback function. : )

Comment: @xxw Perfect solution. But there is a problem again :) If i select two checkboxes, it's okay. After that i remove a checkbox, second selected checkbox must be get "2". And then if i select another one again, last selected must be "1". Your first code can do that. How can we do that on your last code?

Comment: @OnderYilmaz  you can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kamilic/Ljfygkoc/),and please notice the comment on the code. : )

Comment: @xxw thank you so much. I will check the pop() command because i'm new on jquery :)) And last question, can you remove the show popup when unclick a checkbox?

Comment: @xxw anyway, it's not necessary. Thank you so so so so much :)

Comment: @OnderYilmaz It's easy.You can just move the getArrangement(stack); to  if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) { ... };I have updated the code. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kamilic/Ljfygkoc/)